# Java arrayList element

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have an issue regarding arrayList element while in looping
    I have two lists : the first list contains 2 elements : A and B.
    the second list contains 4 element : A1,B1,B2,B3
    Now, what I want is to get from both the list to match their respective 
    elements 
    For example: A -> A1
    B -> B1
    B -> B2
    B -> B3

```
public class MyArrayList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List listA = new ArrayList<>();
        List listB = new ArrayList<>();
        listA.add("ElementA");
        listA.add("ElementB");
        listB.add("ElementA1");
        listB.add("ElementB1");
        listB.add("ElementB2");
        listB.add("ElementB3");
        listB.add("ElementB4");
        for (int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < listB.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println(listA.get(i) + "-->" + listB.get(j));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "respective elements"? And what is actually your problem?

Comment: Please never use **raw-types** (except you must code on Java versions below 1.5). Instead use generics, `List<String>` for example.

Comment: If you say you have *an issue*, then clearly state the problem. What does your current code do? Does it throw errors? If so, which? If not, what is its current output and what is the desired?

Answer (score 1):

You code got some synax errors. You can print them when element from A is substring of element from B using `String.contains()`.

```
public class MyArrayList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List listA = new ArrayList<>();
        List listB = new ArrayList<>();
        listA.add("ElementA");
        listA.add("ElementB");
        listB.add("ElementA1");
        listB.add("ElementB1");
        listB.add("ElementB2");
        listB.add("ElementB3");
        listB.add("ElementB4");
        for (Object elementFromFirstList : listA) {
            for (Object elementFromSecondList : listB) {
                if (((String) elementFromSecondList).contains(
                        (String) elementFromFirstList)) {
                    System.out.println(elementFromSecondList + "-->" + elementFromFirstList);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you may even shorten it by using for each loops since you never use the iterator value (only for indexing)

Comment: I think better to use Set to check on containing elements